# ASP.NET MVC Performance after publishing on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, for-loop, localhost

In my application site I have a controller action creating and generating an Excel file: from a list of items, it writes every field of every item through a for cycle.
Simplified example (coz I have ~30 fields):

```
String az = "";
az = az + "<table border=\"1\">";
az = az + "<tr>";
az = az + "<th>Field 1</th>";
az = az + "<th>Field 2</th>";
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++){
     az = az + "<tr>";
     az = az + "<td>" + items.ElementAt(i).Field1+ "</td>";
     az = az + "<td>" + items.ElementAt(i).Field2+ "</td>";
     az = az + "</tr>";
}
az = az + "</table>";
```

Now, when I have a few rows, no problem.
When I have a large number of rows, it takes a while generating the file. This is not a problem on localhost, but after I publish the site on IIS it takes until 7x(the time).

Example:

Loading **250 rows**: *0,8s* on localhost, *4s* on IIS

Loading **615 rows**: *4s* on localhost, *21s* on IIS

Loading **950 rows**: *7s* on localhost, *38s* on IIS

Loading **1300 rows**: *15s* on localhost, *104s* on IIS

Does anyone know what the problem is? Do I have to change/set some variable on the IIS site? In case I haven't to, is there a way to optimize the performance on IIS?

Thanks, hope someone can help me!

Comment: This will not kill your performance, but you should use StringBuilder to concatenate strings as you do.

Comment: What do you mean by "generating an Excel file"? Are you automating Excel and creating an actual XLS or XLSX file? Are you using a different tool to create the file? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: @Lukas No, you're completely wrong: indeed, it does kill my performance. Now it builds the string in less than 1 second, whatever the number of rows, both on localhost and on IIS! Thank you very much!

Comment: Wow - so impact is far bigger than expected. Pleased to hear that it's fast now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off if you have to build your html like this then at least use a string builder

```
var az = new StringBuilder();
az.append("<table border=\"1\">");
az.append("<tr>");
//etc
return az.ToString();
```

However, it might well be worthwhile to reconsider this approach entirely and look at using a Razor view instead of compiling your html.  Of course this depends on other considerations you might have.